Running a .exe file in Go Module
I am writing a Go module in which I want to run a .exe file. I am running the .exe as following in the module code.
cmd := exec.Command("./net/myapp.exe")
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()

This module is uploaded to for example the following github. github.com/moizhassan/my-module
When this module is imported and used I get error as the .exe file isn't available in the directory. As the exec.Command is running in the working directory of the project which imported the module rather than the module directory. I can see that the exe file is available at GOPATH + /github.com/moizhassan/my-module/golang@v0.0.xxxxx/net/myapp.exe.
Another problem that I thought might be that when someone imports my module in their application, they might have the .exe in there GOPATH but when someone is using compiled application how would my .exe go into the compiled code? How can I include my .exe so that it runs even when the go code is compiled into an exe?

After the main application is compiled, there is no longer any relationship to the source directories. You need to provide the binary separately (or embed it) for the main application to locate.

@JimB Any idea how to do it? I am thinking about using github.com/omeid/go-resources/cmd/resources@latest to convert the .exe into binary and save as a .go file which can then be written to a temp location and then running the .exe

Maybe use the builtin embed package?
